# Unable to configure log4j2 for logging in Maven project on VS Code

Tags: java, maven, log4j2

I have added the dependencies in pom.xml: log4j-api (2.17.0) and log4j-core (2.17.0).

Java version on Windows 10 is "17.0.1" 2021-10-19 LTS

I have put the file log4j2.yml is src/main/resources folder. But it appears that this file is never read. I am able to log to console but it's not formatted based on what I have configured in log file. Likewise, I can't log to file since config file is never read.

I am using Maven on VS Code. App itself is rather simple:

```
package com.example;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App 
{
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(App.class);

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        logger.error("Hello Logger!");
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
    }
}
```

Actual output on execution is as follows:

```
C:\Users\userme\Documents\workspace\java-sample> c: && cd c:\Users\userme\Documents\workspace\java-sample && cmd /C ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.1\bin\java.exe" -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages @C:\Users\USERME\AppData\Local\Temp\cp_a2ngr445g97bq5yjwdq9bbcx.argfile com.example.App "        
23:13:36.471 [main] ERROR com.example.App - Hello Logger!
Hello World!
```

YAML file:

```
Configuration:
  name: Default
  Properties:
    Property:
      name: log-path
      value: "logs"
  Appenders:
    Console:
      name: Console_Appender
      target: SYSTEM_OUT
      PatternLayout:
        pattern: "[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"
    File:
      name: File_Appender
      fileName: ${log-path}/logfile.log
      PatternLayout:
        pattern: "[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"
  Loggers:
      Root:
        level: debug
        AppenderRef:
          - ref: Console_Appender
      Logger:
        - name: com.example.App
          level: debug
          AppenderRef:
            - ref: File_Appender
              level: debug
```

Comment: When you place files under `src/main/resources`, then please run with maven/gradle or ensure (yourself) it is available "on classpath"/at expected location...

Comment: Not sure how to check classpath but in folder `target/classes` I see the yml config file along with the `com` folder. It suggests that yml file is recognized by maven but nothing is happening at runtime.

Comment: I added CLASSPATH env variable and set it to the absolute path of resources folder (not ideal but just checking if it works). It didn't work.

Comment: ok, sounds good! Did you add "additional runtime" dependencies?? (Jackson databind and YAML data format, "Additional runtime dependencies are required for using YAML configuration files." source:  https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Configuration_with_YAML)

Comment: @werx593 you're a life saver! I didn't realize there was an extra dependency for YAML. It works! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Fine print hero" struck again! :-)
From [log4j2 Configuration reference](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Configuration_with_YAML):

> **Additional runtime dependencies are required for using YAML configuration files**.

These are (as of today):

```
<jackson.version>2.14</jackson.version> <!-- 2021/12/26(, merry x-mas!) -->
<!-- ... -->
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
<version>${jackson.version}</version>
<scope>runtime</scope> <!-- ! -->
<!-- ... -->
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
<!-- As: -->
<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
<artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
<!-- ... -->
```

- https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core/
- https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/
- https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text (since 2.9)
- https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-yaml (before 2.9)